# Проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: кодировка, php

Проблема с кодировкой. Получай сайт.

```
 $news = file_get_contents('http://www.vesti.ru/doc.html?id=1148657');
```

В итоге вместо русских символов получается ромбики с вопросительными знаками. Но не во всех областях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам просто данные приходят не в той кодировке, которая у Вас.

Сайт, с которым Вы работаете в кодировке **windows-1251**. У вас очевидно другая. Если у Вас винда то можно сделать **chcp1251** в консоли. Либо можно с помощью **iconv** перегнать кодировку в нужную Вам.

Comment: Странно mb_detect_encoding(ile_get_contents('http://www.vesti.ru/doc.html?id=1148657')) возвращал UTF-8

Comment: @Zow, та ну, там же в коде четко прописано <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">